# JSON syntax confusion

Tags: android, ios, json, parsing

I am working with an api where I am retrieving JSON data. I've come across a data type that I am unfamiliar with and I would like some insight into what it means.

An example is shown below.

```
{     
   "data":{  
      "id":"92",
      "name":"harry",
      "friends":"a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"1\";i:1;s:2:\"15\";}"
      "enemies":"a:0:{}"
    },
   "error":false
}
```

I am unsure how to interpret the "friends" and "enemies" fields. I am aware that arrays are represented by [ ] and objects by { }.

Could anyone explain what they mean?

Thank you.

Comment: The `friends` and `enemies` fields look like arrays that have been serialised by PHP.

Comment: Would data represented in this way be impossible/difficult to read via anything other than PHP?

Comment: The format is fairly straightforward. You could write a function to parse the strings quite easily, provided you have some idea of what the data represents once you've unserialised it.

Comment: Note that this also isn't valid JSON.  There should be a ',' after the value for the "friends" field, before the "enemies" tag.

Answer (score 0):

The fields contain arrays that have been serialized by PHP.

For example

```
<?php
  $friends = "a:2:{i:0;s:1:\"1\";i:1;s:2:\"15\";}";
  $arr = unserialize($friends);
  var_dump($arr);
?>
```

gives

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(2) "15"
}
```

What these values represent will be application-specific.

Answer (score -1):

The value of friends is a string with the value: a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:2:"15";}

What this string represents depends on what the application does with it

Comment: We have a phrase for this where I work: _'stating the obvious'_